# Efficient way to load all contacts and all phone numbers (Android 2.0)

Tags: android, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient way to load all contacts and all phone numbers (Android 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161627/efficient-way-to-load-all-contacts-and-all-phone-numbers-android-2-0)

Is there a way of getting all the phone numbers for all contacts without doing a separate query for each contact? (using Android 2.0+). It's really slow currently if you have over 100 contacts, I wondered if I could do a more efficient query.

Currently I'm getting a cursor with all valid ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP  contacts then a separate query for each contact to get all their numbers.

Snippet from the get Contacts just geting name and lookup key:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY};
```

Then each contact using the lookup key.

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
Uri res = ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(contentResolver, lookupUri);

String[] projection =  new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};
```

Comment: @scottytab nope, to a duplicate.