# Efficient way to load all contacts and all phone numbers (Android 2.0)

Tags: android, contacts

Is there a way of getting all the phone numbers for all contacts without doing a separate query for each contact? (using Android 2.0+). It's really slow if you have over 100 contacts (unusable on low end phones), I wondered if I could do a more efficient query.

Currently I'm getting a cursor with all valid ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP  contacts then a separate query for each contact to get all their numbers.

Snippet from the get Contacts just geting name and lookup key:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY};
```

Then each contact using the lookup key.

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
Uri res = ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(contentResolver, lookupUri);

String[] projection =  new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};
```

...

```
Cursor phones = contentResolver.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, phoneProjection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

Comment: You're right must of submitted the form twice. Good Spot. Voted to close.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check if the below code helps

```
    public ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> getAllPhoneContacts() {
    Log.d("START","Getting all Contacts");
    ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> arrContacts = new ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo>();
    PhoneContactInfo phoneContactInfo=null;     
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID}, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        String contactNumber= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));  
        String contactName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        int phoneContactID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));


        phoneContactInfo = new PhoneContactInfo();
        phoneContactInfo.setPhoneContactID(phoneContactID);             
        phoneContactInfo.setContactName(contactName);                   
        phoneContactInfo.setContactNumber(contactNumber); 
        if (phoneContactInfo != null)
        {
            arrContacts.add(phoneContactInfo);
        }
        phoneContactInfo = null; 
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }       
    cursor.close();
    cursor = null;
    Log.d("END","Got all Contacts");
    return arrContacts;
}
```

Comment: nice one, reduced load time from 8.7s to 2.4s :)

Comment: after inserting fresh contact into native how can i get native contact id