# how to add search functionality in edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to add search functionality in android . Whenever I enter the any letter all contacts started with this letter will be showed in an listview which is as follows :

[image]

How can I search this entered letter in contact list ? How can I show search result in an listview as in picture ?

I know this can be done AutoCompleteTextView But I can not search over contacts . How can I do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android

Comment: What you are asking is called `AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: It depends.... SearchView is available for Actionbar/Toolbar. As for a simple EditText, you could use @1615903 answer, the AutoCompleteTextView of Frank or you could use addTextChangedListener to search over an API if the query needs to be from a Server.

Comment: How can I search in contactlist using AutoCompleteTextView ? How can I show search result in list as in picture ?

Comment: use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, get your `Cursor` using `ContentResolver#query` with  `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`

Comment: Can you please put this as answer ? can you please tell a bit more about how can be this done ?

Comment: How can I search over contacts ?

Comment: get your `Cursor` using `ContentResolver#query` with `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`

Comment: Can you give an example how to do this ?

Comment: see [this code snippet](http://pastebin.com/UjUzJxzc)

Comment: I hope this is not a list of actual phone numbers to your friends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load all the contacts in array list or string array and then use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) for adding search functionallity

Gett all contacts like this as expalined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238210/3593066)

```
public ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> getAllPhoneContacts() {

    Log.d("START","Getting all Contacts");
    ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> arrContacts = new ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo>();
    PhoneContactInfo phoneContactInfo=null;     
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID}, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        String contactNumber= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));  
        String contactName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        int phoneContactID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));


        phoneContactInfo = new PhoneContactInfo();
        phoneContactInfo.setPhoneContactID(phoneContactID);             
        phoneContactInfo.setContactName(contactName);                   
        phoneContactInfo.setContactNumber(contactNumber); 
        if (phoneContactInfo != null)
        {
            arrContacts.add(phoneContactInfo);
        }
        phoneContactInfo = null; 
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }       
    cursor.close();
    cursor = null;
    Log.d("END","Got all Contacts");
    return arrContacts;
}
```

Comment: How can I load all contacts in array list ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use AutoCompleteTextView 
for helpful link : http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example

Comment: How can I search over contacts ? Please give an example about this .

Comment: for Example : http://androidexample.com/Show_Phone_Contacts_In_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=106&aaid=128